# Pandas Dataframe days difference with zeros and null values: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Dataframe with dates. I simply want to fill a new column with a difference of maximum end and minimum start dates and find the length of days.
My calculation is working but when if either column contains zero or Nan values it's going to give me this error.
Does anyone can look at the code and give a suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

```
# here is the Dataframe
    end_d                   start_d                 
0   2021-09-11 00:00:00     2021-08-01 00:00:00     
1   2021-08-29 00:00:00     2021-05-23 00:00:00     
2   2021-09-04 00:00:00     2021-06-13 00:00:00     
3   0                       0                       
4   0                       0                       
5   0                       0                       
6   0                       0                       
7   0                       0                       
8   NaN                     NaN                     
9   NaN                     NaN                     
10  2021-09-04 00:00:00     2021-06-13 00:00:00
11
12
13

#When I use the below code if there aren't any zeros or Nan values, the code is working fine.

dsx['length'] = (dsx['end_d'] - dsx['start_d'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit=freq)).max()  

# I want something like, below Dataframe. Any suggestion?
    
    end_d                   start_d                 length
0   2021-09-11 00:00:00     2021-08-01 00:00:00     99 days
1   2021-08-29 00:00:00     2021-05-23 00:00:00     99 days
2   2021-09-04 00:00:00     2021-06-13 00:00:00     99 days
3   0                       0                       99 days
4   0                       0                       99 days
5   0                       0                       99 days
6   0                       0                       99 days
7   0                       0                       99 days
8   NaN                     NaN                     99 days
9   NaN                     NaN                     99 days
10  2021-09-04 00:00:00     2021-06-13 00:00:00     99 days

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataframe for non-N/A values with skipna.

[pandas.Dataframe.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
filtered_df = df.dropna()
df['length'] = (filtered_df['end_d'] - filtered_df['start_d'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit=freq)).max()
```

That takes care of your N/A problem, but you still have an issue where your columns are filled with different data types (int and datetime). Not sure what's up there but you need to fix that.